# MySQL connection with Jython using com.mysql.jdbc import Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jython, grinder

I am working on Grinder framework for testing the MySQL DB load test. I am able to connect the MySQL DB but unable to execute the queries and I didn't get any error message also. My question is How to execute the queries in grinder framework(Grinder will work on Jython).

Please find the below Jython script and program is executing up-to " print "test1 record" " step, after that it simple skip the steps, Any thing wrong in that program like in queries?

```
from java.sql import DriverManager
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test
from com.mysql.jdbc import Driver

test1 = Test(1, "Database insert")
test2 = Test(2, "Database query")

#Load the MySQL JDBC driver.
DriverManager.registerDriver(Driver())

def getConnection():
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
"root", "Sasken@123")

def ensureClosed(object):
    try: object.close()
    except: pass

class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
        connection = None
        insertStatement = None
        queryStatement = None
        print "connection"
        try:
            connection = getConnection()
            insertStatement = connection.createStatement()
            print "try connection"
            test1.record(insertStatement)
            print "test1 record"
            insertStatement.execute("insert into testing values(%d)"
(100))
            print "insert"
            test2.record(queryStatement)
            print "test2 record"
            queryStatement.executeQuery("select * from testing")
            print "select"
        except SyntaxError:
                         print "can\'t execute db"

        finally:
            ensureClosed(insertStatement)
            ensureClosed(queryStatement)
            ensureClosed(connection)

Thanks Advance.
```